# How to write an update hook for git submodules?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, git-submodules, githooks, braid

I would like to copy some files in the submodules in my "vendor/assets" directory to another directory -- "public/assets." I heard about update hooks but I am not sure if they work for submodules. I wrote a simple hook and ran update from commandline, but it didn't work.

My update hook looks like this:

```
#.git/gooks/update.rb

#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Copying files..."
```

So is this even possible?

btw, I'm using Braid to manage my submodules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` hook is only run when someone has pushed into the current repository, which doesn't sound like what you want.  You could use the `post-commit` hook, if you want to copy these files into place every time you create a commit in your repository.  (That should be sufficient, because you'd need to commit the new version of any submodule in the main project when you change the commit that the submodule is meant to be at.  This would be a natural point to update the files in `public/assets`.)

You say that your test hook isn't being run - that may be simply because you have the name wrong.  The update hook must be an executable file called `.git/hooks/update` (n.b. without a `.rb` suffix).  Similarly, a post-commit hook must be `.git/hooks/post-commit`.

You shouldn't create hooks in any particular submodule for this task, since the action the hook will be taking is specific to the main project.  Because of that, it doesn't really matter whether the change you're worried about it due to committing a new version of the submodules or just updating any random file.

For writing hooks, you'll find the [official githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) documentation useful, and possibly these [additional tips](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/).

Comment: I see. But wouldn't the best hook to use be pre-commit? That way the copied files would also be included in the commit.

Comment: Oh, I had assumed that these files were going to be untracked.  I'm not sure if you can stage additional files in a `pre-commit` hook, I'm afraid, but it's easy to test...

Comment: Yes, that seems to work fine, although the files you `git add` in the `pre-commit` hook don't appear in the helpful commented-out part of the commit message.